# net start "Error 5: Access is denied"

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a script that i start using Windows 7 Task Manager. The Task Manager is configured to start not depending on my logging status (login/logout).

At some point of the script i call

```
net start > foo.log
```

If i am logged on, foo.log file is not empty. If i am not logged on, the size of foo.log is zero and i get the error:

```
Error 5: Access is denied.
```

Is the command *net start* depends on my logging status?

If yes, how could i start *net start* alought i am not logged?

**Additional Info**
Hear is an export of my task setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2015-01-08T07:30:09.6060087</Date>
    <Author>Jone Doe</Author>
    <Description>NightlyBuild</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2015-01-09T22:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>Jone Doe</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
  <Command>boo.bat</Command>
</Exec>
```

Comment: Exactly how did you setup the task?  Which user is it using?  Do you have "run with highest privileges" set in the Task? etc.  Perhaps export the task to an XML file  and edit the XML contents into your question so we can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set high priority.